# Rails active storage, update the image when has-many_attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using rais api for backend and react for frontend.

I am using rails active storage to handle images.

In my rails application, I have modal names `Post`.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :pictures

  def picture_url
    if self.pictures.attached?
      self.pictures.map do |picture|
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(picture, 
        only_path: true)
      end
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

So according to above one `post` can have many images.

Now I am facing problem in updating the post's pictures.

case 1: Suppose I have a post let say 'p1', p1 has now 3 pictures. Now if I would like to remove one of the image from p1 and add a new image in place of the removed image. How will I handle it in my controller.

case 2: I want to keep only one image from 3 images. That means I want to remove the particular 2 images.

My `update` action of `posts_controller.rb` looks like:

```
  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if post.update_attributes(message: params[:message], picture: 
       params[:picture])
      render_success(:ok, post, meta: { message: 'Post updated' })
    else
      render_error(422, post.errors, message: 'Failed to update post')
    end
  end
```